# how to get the network ip address (Internet) using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ip-address, lan

i am developing asp.net website , now my problem is how to get the lan connected ip address using c# code , for example open http://whatismyipaddress.com/ display the IP Information: 183.82.77.56 like that i have to get ip address , now i am writing like this

```
//Get Lan Connected IP address method
        public string GetLanIPAddress()
        {
            //Get the Host Name
            string stringHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            //Get The Ip Host Entry
            IPAddress[] arrIpAddress1 = Dns.GetHostAddresses(stringHostName);

            IPHostEntry ipHostEntries = Dns.GetHostEntry(stringHostName);
            //Get The Ip Address From The Ip Host Entry Address List
            IPAddress[] arrIpAddress = ipHostEntries.AddressList;
            return arrIpAddress[arrIpAddress.Length - 1].ToString();
        }
        //Get Visitor IP address method
        public string GetVisitorIpAddress()
        {
            string stringIpAddress;
            stringIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (stringIpAddress == null) //may be the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is null
            {
                stringIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];//we can use REMOTE_ADDR
                string add = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }
            return "Your ip is " + stringIpAddress;
        }
```

but wrong outputs, please help me any one.

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code

```
        foreach (IPAddress ipaddress in ipHostEntries.AddressList)
        {
            IPStr = ipaddress.ToString();
            return IPStr;
        }
        return IPStr;
```

try this gateway address will be you required

```
   IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        Console.WriteLine(ipProperties.HostName);

        foreach (NetworkInterface networkCard in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation gatewayAddr in networkCard.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Information: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Interface type: {0}", networkCard.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", networkCard.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", networkCard.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", networkCard.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Gateway address: {0}", gatewayAddr.Address.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("IP: {0}", System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Speed: {0}", networkCard.Speed);
                Console.WriteLine("MAC: {0}", networkCard.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: below this line                                                                           IPHostEntry ipHostEntries = Dns.GetHostEntry(stringHostName);

Comment: output was AddressList count have 4, 1 is {fe80::c90d:59f2:6d65:8100%11},2 is {fe80::18d7:2872:3f57:fe35%12}, and 3 is {192.168.1.202}(my pc ip) , 4 is {2001:0:9d38:953c:18d7:2872:3f57:fe35} but i have 183.82.77.56(this is my bandwidth ip)

Comment: how to get that ip please give me some idea

Comment: which ip you required your ip or bandwidth ip?

Comment: bandwidth ip (that means airtel or tikona like that ) for example http://whatismyipaddress.com/ display the bandwidth ip like that